# Prove that $card(X) \le card(Y) \iff \exists Z \subseteq Y$ such that $card(X)=card(Z)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I would just like some guidance on whether my proof is sufficient, or if there are things I should change. Thank you!

Prove that $card(X) \le card(Y) \iff \exists Z \subseteq Y$ such that $card(X)=card(Z)\\$

Assume $\exists Z \subseteq Y$ such that $card(X)=card(Z)$

$\Rightarrow card(Z) \le card(Y)$

$\Rightarrow card(X) \le card(Y)$ since $card(X)=card(Z)$

$\therefore$ $card(X) \le card(Y)\\$

Assume $card(X) \le card(Y)$

$\Rightarrow$ There is an injective function $f: X\rightarrow Y$

Now let $Z$ be the image of $f$

$\Rightarrow Z\subseteq Y$

$\Rightarrow$ Then for $\forall a \in X,\exists b \in Z$ such that $f(a)=b$

Let $g:X \rightarrow Z$ be a function from $X$ to $Z$

$\Rightarrow$ Then since the codomain and image of $g$ are equal, $g$ is an onto function

$\Rightarrow$ $g$ is bijective function

$\Rightarrow$ $card(X)=card(Z)$

$\therefore$ $card(X)=card(Z)$

Comment: You should check the question statement and specify a few things: is $card$ the cardinality function? What is $x$ in the title? (did you mean $X$?). Moreover, are you sure that the inequality on the left side is as intended? I feel like it should contain $Y$ instead of $Z$

Comment: Sorry about that, I have made corrections. I did mean $X$, and I have corrected the inequality as well. 
Yes, $card$ is the cardinality function.
Thank you for pointing those out.

Answer (score 1):

Overall, the proof is correct, the only thing you probably missed is that you forgot to define what $g(x)$ is, but specifying that $g(x) = f(x)$ is enough to fix it.

In case you want to be extra precise, in order to conclude $card(Z) \leq card(Y)$ you might want to explicitly state that it follows from the existence of the identity function from $Z$ to $Y$.